# coldfusion cfhttp post from within scheduled tasks

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, cfhttp

I have a CF scheduled tasks that emails a summary of phone calls for an admin user.  I want to add the ability to also email a report for certain admin users.  The additional report is dynamic per admin user and is stored in a table.  I can't just  the report code as it may change or not exist for the next user.  Maybe I should use CFHTTP but I'm not versed in it.

```
<cfloop query="qGetTelemateEmails">             
  <cfif trim(QGetTime.Call_Email_On_Hour) eq "" or     listfind(#QGetTime.Call_Email_On_Hour#,datepart("h",now()))>
  <cfset TotalTime = 0>
  <cfset NumberOfCalls = 0> 
  <cfmail ........></cfmail>
```

The following code is where I want to also email a report.

```
<cfquery name="QAdditionalReports" datasource="#request.dtsrc#">
Select *
From Admin_Telemate_Additional_Query_Daily as a  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Admin_Users AS C ON A.AdminID = C.adminID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Admin_Telemate_Available_Queries AS b ON A.description = b.description
where a.adminid = #val(QGetTime.call_admin_user_id)#
</cfquery>
<cfif QAdditionalReports.recordcount gt 0>
SEE CODE BELOW  -------------------------------------------------------------       
</cfif>

</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

This is the report code that I want to "include/execute". I get the url of the code from the query table entry.

```
    <cfquery name="QGetCommEct" datasource="#request.dsn#">
      select *
      from Q_ES_Communications_by_Search_Number
      where upper(communication_type) = 'T'
        and Date_Entered = '#dateformat(now(),"yyyy/mm/dd")#'
    and consultant_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.adminid#">
      order by date_Entered
    </cfquery>
    <cfmail>
        <div style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; ">Communications Files Query</div> 
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif x-small; border:1px solid black; ">
         <tr>
      <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Cons</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
         </tr>
     <cfoutput query="QGetCommEct">     
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>#QGetCommEct.Communication_Type#-#QGetCommEct.Category#</td>
          <td>#QGetCommEct.AS400_Initials#</td>
          <td>#QGetCommEct.lastname#</td>
        </tr>
     </cfoutput>      
     </table> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</cfmail>
```

I replaced the cfif QAdditionalReports.recordcount gt 0 with

```
<cfloop query="QAdditionalReports">
<cfhttp url="#QAdditionalReports.QueryURL##QAdditionalReports.QueryName#?adminid=#val(QGetTime.call_admin_user_id)#&emailto=#qGetTelemateEmails.Telemate_Email#">
<cfmail to="vj@gmail.com" from="server@tt.com" subject="Recap of daily phone calls" type="html" spoolenable="false"><cfdump var="#cfhttp#"></cfmail>
</cfloop>
```

And the email contains;

```
struct
Charset [empty string] 
ErrorDetail [empty string] 
Filecontent [empty string] 
Header  HTTP/1.1 503 Server Error Content-Type: text/html Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2013 15:11:17 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0 
Mimetype    text/html 
Responseheader  struct
Content-Type    text/html 
Date    Wed, 13 Feb 2013 15:11:17 GMT 
Explanation Server Error 
Http_Version    HTTP/1.1 
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.0 
Status_Code 503 

Statuscode  503 Server Error 
Text    YES
```

It could be that I need to do an HTTPS

Comment: `cfhttp` is extremely simple. check out the docs - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_09.html

Comment: I'm not seeing where cfhttp comes into this equation.

Comment: I don't know of another way to dynamically execute a page from another cfml page. And what I'm doing above gets me an error message 503.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code you're trying to reuse and "remotely call" in a cfc or include it with cfinclude.

Writing a CFC would be the better way to go. [Here is some documentation.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=UseFlexDataService_05.html)

```
<cfcomponent ...>
   <cffunction name = "additionalReports" ...>
      <cfargument name = "adminid" ...>
      <cfargument name = "emailto" ...>

      <!--- dynamic query using your adminid here ---->

      <cfmail to = "#arguments.emailTo#" ...>
         <!--- nicely formated output --->
      </cfmail>
   </cffunction>
<cfcomponent>
```

You would call the cfc in your scheduled task like this

```
<!--- make the object. assume the cfc is in the same folder named adminreports.cfc --->
<cfset reportObject = createObject("component", "adminReports")>
<cfset reportObject.additionalReports(val(QGetTime.call_admin_user_id), qGetTelemateEmails.Telemate_Email)>
```

Comment: I guess I could put a cfinclude in the cffunction. But what happens when I get to the next user and they have a different "additional report" to cfinclude.  Doesn't the cffunction still contain the include from the previous call?  And what's the duration of the cfcomponent.  I run this process every hour during the day.

Comment: why do you have different files for each report? I'm still only understanding part of what you're trying to accomplish.  Sorry.  the CFC lives for the duration of the request so each time the process is run it creates a new object.

Comment: but either way, you can use cfinclude with a dynamic page name, assuming queryName is your file name: `<cfinclude template = #QAdditionalReports.QueryName#?adminid=#val(QGetTime.call_admin_user_id)#&emailto=#qGetTelemateEmails.Telemate_Email#">`

Comment: I have 10 admin users that make calls all day long. Every hour I email them a summary of their calls. This is run from CF scheduled tasks. While looping over the query (group by admin id) I look to see if there is an additional report(s) for the user.  If there is, I'm trying to do a CFHTTP to produce the report. The next user may have a different report.  It seems like the only logical way to produce the reports. A CFINCLUDE would stay in memory for the next user and they would "stack up".

Comment: are the "additional report(s)" derived from 1 or more coldfusion page that you have control over?

Comment: ok, so they have requested custom reports, I see. you should be able to include them into the processing like I suggested in the 3rd comment.